# Вызов функции массива

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня функция, которая выводит "Привет, + имена из массива names, но только те, что заданы.)
Как сделать, чтобы я наполнял данный массив из клавиатуры, и вывод осуществлялся всех имен, что были введены? И чтобы кол-во имен в массиве names зависело от того, сколько я решил ввести.
Я могу сразу через var задать все имена в массив, но тогда перед каждым вызовом функции мне нужно менять массив.

```js
var names = ['Вася', 'Петя', 'Коля'];

function Hi() {
  alert("Hello," + names)
}

Hi()
```

Comment: http://learn.javascript.ru удачи :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используемые методы:

- window.[prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)
- window.[confirm()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm)
- window.[alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)
- [тернарный оператор](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) `(условие ? выражение1 : выражение2)`
- array.[push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- array.[join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
// Объявляем массив с именами.
const names = [];

function enterName() {
 // Отображаем диалоговое окно для ввода имени.
 const name = prompt('Введите имя: ');
 
 // Уточняем у пользователя нужно ли продолжить ввод имен.
 const status = confirm("Продолжить ввод?");
 
 // Если имя не содержит пустую строк, добавляем в массив методом push()
 if (name) names.push(name);
 
 // Если мы продолжили ввод, то по тернарному оператору обращаемся опять к этой же функции, в ином случае переходим в функцию printNames()
 status ? enterName() : printNames();
}

function printNames() {
 // Отображаем диалоговое окно, в котором мы конкатенируем строки и с помощью метода join() объединяем значения в массиве через запятую и пробел, в конце добавляем точку. 
 alert('Hello, ' + names.join(', ') + '.');
}

// Вызываем функцию enterName();
enterName();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Поле - ввод, с помощью querySelector() получаем первый элемент DOM.
const input = document.querySelector('input');

// Кнопка
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// Блок, в который будем выводить имена
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

// Пустой массив с именами
const names = [];

// Функция pushName()
const pushName = () => {
 // Проверяем не было ли пустое значение у поля
 if (!input.value) return;
 
 // Добавляем в массив значение поля
 names.push(input.value);
 
 // Выводим строку в блок output
 output.innerHTML = `Hello, ${names.join(', ')}.`;
 
 // Обнуляем значение переменной
 input.value = '';
}

// Вешаем слушатель на кнопку, в качестве события у нас будет клик, в качестве callback функции передадим нашу функцию pushName.
button.addEventListener('click', pushName);
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Имя">
<button>Добавить</button>
<br>
<p class="output">Hello!</p>
```

Comment: комментарии всегда нужны

Comment: почему проверка input.value вынесена из функции pushName?

Comment: @Grundy да я изначально хотел другой ответ написать и черт меня дернул пихать еще форму, я поправил немного код и сейчас добавлю комментарии.